# Family of sets base of standard topology of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology

Suppose we have the standard topology of $\mathbb{R}$ which is $\mathcal{F}$ can somebody help me prove that the family of sets $\mathcal{B}=\left \{ (p,q):p,q:\mathbb{Q},p<q \right \}$ forms a base for $\mathcal{F}$ ??

It is clear that $\mathcal{B}$ is open , but I have a hard time to show that for every open set on $\mathcal{F}$ we can write it as a union of sets of $\mathcal{B}$.Maybe it has to do that we can always find and irrational between to rationals ??

Any advise would be really helpful.

Comment: No, it probably has more to do with the fact that you can always find a *rational* number between any two numbers.

Comment: any two numbers generaly so I suppose and irrationals.

Answer (score 0):

Assume r < s. Then there is a
decreasing sequence of rational numbers r_n that converges to r and an
increasing sequence of rational numbers s_n that converges to s.
Thus (r,s) = $\cup$ { (r_n,s_n) : n in N }.

Answer (score 0):

Do we agree that $\mathcal R:=\{(a,b)\mid a,b\in\Bbb R\wedge a<b\}$ is a basis? Then see here how every $(a,b)\in\mathcal R$ can be build from sets in $\mathcal Q:=\{(a,b)\mid a,b\in\Bbb Q\wedge a<b\}$.

Choose some decreasing sequence $a_n\in\Bbb Q$ with $a_n\to a$ and some increasing sequence $b_n\in \Bbb Q$ with $b_n\to b$. Then

$$\bigcup_n (a_n,b_n)=(a,b).$$

As you can build any open set from $\mathcal R$ and any set in $\mathcal R$ from $\mathcal Q$, we can build any open set from $\mathcal Q$ itself.

---

Here is another direct way. Given an open set $X\subseteq \Bbb R$. Can you see why

$$X=\bigcup\{(a,b)\in\mathcal Q\mid (a,b)\subseteq X\}$$

holds? If yes, then you see why it is a basis.